# In Javascript there is a function working like 'slice' but having more control of elements taken at the boundaries?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to manipulate a string taking dynamically some part of it with variable start and end index. I know that there are three main functions to manipulate string cutting in javascript: [Javascript string functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp)

Slice, substr and substring, though have some problems:

- the start index is taken, the end index is not taken. It would be great to control such a behaviour, like having two more parameters so that you can choose to include or not include first and last index character.
- start and end, in my case, are dynamical so it could happen that start=end. In this case, the functions returns empty string, while the return I expect in that case is the single character at index start=end

There is a function in javascript or typescript, i'm presently missing, that could satisfy one or all of these features?

Comment: Build your own version?

Comment: Obviously... Thought there was something more 'official' and built better I could do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can’t you just add 1 to the end index? Now it will be included and also return a character when the start and end endex are the same.

```
let str = "hallo"
let start = 2
let end = 4
let result = str.substring(start,end+1)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yes, I did not notice the fact that it goes till the end of the array if end if greater than its lenght. This does not solve the problem if start=end but this can easily solve with a custom function returning the char at start=end index (using a charAt) if they are the same. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please remember though, this all fails when dealing with enhanced unicode,.. eg. `"halo".substring(2, 4+1)` will give you `"l"`

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with strings in Javascript, if you want to do fancy stuff, it's usually better to convert into an array.

There are a couple of advantages then,..

1. All array functions can then be used, like `splice`, `map` etc..
2. Unicode is handled correctly..  eg. if you have a glyth that's can't be fit inside a UTF16 codepoint, it's doesn't get split into 2.

eg.

```js
//a string with 2 glyths.
var astring = "";
//oops, length says 4..
console.log(astring);
console.log("String length: " + astring.length);

var a = Array.from(astring);
console.log("As array: " + a.length);
//ah that's better says 2 now

//lets remove the first glyth
console.log("Lets remove first glyth");
a.splice(0,1);
//now join back to create new string.
console.log(a.join(""));
```